# Need assitance with data element passing JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Can anyone tell me why this code wont work? It works for anything else but for some reason when I use img in front it doesnt work. Only works with p tags etc. Also im using JSON and this data element is being passed from a loop.

```
 var clickedItemImage = '<img class="img-responsive img-rounded center-block" src="' + $(this).data('itemimage'); + '">';
```

Something like this does work for me though. Not sure why I cant use src in front of it:

```
var clickedItemDescription = '<p>' + $(this).data('itemdescription'); + '</p>';
```

Comment: what do you mean it doesn't work? Does it give you an invalid src value? that wouldn't have anything at all to do with the image element. probably not the json either.

Comment: it does not show the image on the page

Comment: obviously, it's because whatever `$(this).data('itemimage');` returns isn't pointing to an image. we can't really help you with that.

Comment: though, i assume the extra `;` is a typo, because otherwise neither of those would work.

Comment: @kevin it is ill update my code above. and if i right click it doesnt show anything in the page. its in a JSON file

Comment: that doesn't change my comment in any way shape or form. You are giving the image tag a src that it cannot render an image from. It is not because you are using .data(), it's be cause the data you are giving it is wrong.

Comment: @kevin that was my problem the extra semicolon...wow lol but thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As Kevin stated it was the semicolon. Problem solved.